# How to perform jqXHR.always on jquery form plugin .ajaxSubmit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

This one works:

```
    $.post('url', {
       ...
    }, function(resp) {
       ...
    }, 'json').always(function() {
       ...
    });
```

This one produces "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function":

```
    $form.ajaxSubmit({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            ...
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            ...
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            ...
        },
        success: function(response, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            ...
        }
    }).always(function() {
            ...
    });
```

It asks me to write more about my code, which is silly because the question is quite complete and writing more words will not make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The [.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) method belongs to the promise object, the ajaxSubmit() method does not return a promise, it returns the jQuery object on which it was called on.

You can use the complete callback

```
$form.ajaxSubmit({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        //...
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSubmit: function () {
        // ...
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        // ...
    },
    success: function (response, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        // ...
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log('completed')
    }
})
```

Comment: In jQuery core .complete was declared as outdated, will it always be available? Also .complete is not documented at plugin home page.